# How can I successfully checkout my coworker's repository?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I typed the following expressions into the command line:

```
 git remote add coworkerBranch git://coworkersUsername/repo.git
 git fetch origin
 git checkout coworkerBranch
```

However, when I checked the files on my local drive, they weren't altered to match my coworker's changes. I'm new to this whole git syntax so I may be completely off, but is there anything else I need to do to access his files?

Comment: Try `git checkout coworkerBranch; git pull` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't checkout a remote (see "[Working with remotes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)"): you fetch from it, and checkout one of its branch:

```
git remote add coworker git://coworkersUsername/repo.git
git fetch coworker 
git branch --all # choose a branch
git checkout --track -b aBranch coworker/aBranch
```

(See "[Working with remote branches](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)")

"`coworker`" is the name for a reference to a coworker repo, which is different than "`origin`".
"`origin`" references the original repo you cloned.
But you can add as many other **[upstream repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309)** you want/need.